# Convert List<dynamic> to List<String>

Tags: json, list, dart

I am getting data from server. The run `runtimeType` shows that they have type List.
Currently I am using `cast<String>()` to get `List<String>`.

But is it's only\right way?

```
   var value = await http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5001/regions');

   if(value.statusCode == 200) {  
      return jsonDecode(value.body)['data'].cast<String>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways, depending on how soon you want an error if the list contains a non-string, and how you're going to use the list.

- `list.cast<String>()` creates a *lazy wrapper* around the original list. It checks on *each read* that the value is actually a `String`. If you plan to read often, all that type checking might be expensive, and if you want an early error if the last element of the list is not a string, it won't do that for you.
- `List<String>.from(list)` creates a new list of `String` and copies each element from `list` into the new list, checking along the way that it's actually a `String`. This approach errs early if a value isn't actually a string. After creation, there are no further type checks. On the other hand, creating a new list costs extra memory.
- `[for (var s in list) s as String]`,
- `[... list.cast<String>()]`,
- `<String>[for (var s in list) s]`,
- `<String>[... list]` are all other ways to create a new list of strings. The last two relies on implicit downcast from `dynamic`, the first two uses explicit casts.

I recommend using list literals where possible. Here, I'd probably go for the smallest version `<String>[...list]`, *if* you want a new list. Otherwise `.cast<String>()` is fine.